# How do I code a BTN in an HTML project to open a users email client

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to HTML and CSS and trying to  build something which resembles a homepage.

Please see screenshot.

As you can see, I have a couple of bootstrap buttons deployed in the Jumbotron. I would like these BTN's when clicked to open up the users email client in the form of a mailto action in a target blank.

I would be grateful to know how to code this please.

[image]

> My HTML

```
<div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Bespoke Recruitment Solutions</h1>
        <p class="lead">We are an independant recruitment company based in Leicester specialising in providing bespoke HR services.<br> We take the time to understand our clients vision, goals and culture allowing us to engage with the right talent to fill the vacancy.</p>
        <p class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Submit Your CV</a><a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" role="button">Fill A Vacancy</a></p>
      </div>
```

Comment: Kind of hard to do - you won't know how the user sends email (could be gmail, yahoo, etc)

Comment: You seem to know that you need to use `mailto:` so where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I've only been coding 2 months!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a **mailto** link, using the `href` attribute. Like

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="mailto:test@example.com" target="_blank" role="button">Submit Your CV</a>
```

It also depends what the users uses as default E-Mail client, but should open by itself.

You may also add more options to the E-Mail, like the subject:

```
mailto:test@example.com?subject=My CV?cc=someoneelse@example.com
```

Comment: I know you're new to coding. This is very basic HTML. Consider Google first. Keep up the work ;)